# Rails params cannot retrieve

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/842/probx.png/

Sorry I don't have enough reputation to post an Image..

Above is a screenshot from my Netbeans IDE when I'am debugging. I found out there is no data in my `params[:user_ids]`. But then the console says there is, so what's wrong with this?

Comment: Did you resolve your issue?  I'd be interested to hear how it went.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a glance, you don't seem to have the right action shown there.  From your picture, it shows that you are accessing the *index* action, yet you are looking at the *reg* action.

Your log file indicates:

> Processing RoleController#index

From the main view, I see:

```
 def reg
   @role_id = params[:user_ids]
   ...
 end
```

Also, posting code snippets directly will always be helpful in addressing these issues.

Comment: Wow! you're good!..though it doesn't solve my problem, it does shed some light to why is it when I transfer `@role_id = params[:user_ids]` into the index action it does return some values. It still not answered though, but nice one ghayes

Comment: Can you post in a larger snippet of code, e.g. your view code for the action and your controller action.  Screenshots don't make debugging too easy.

Answer (score 0):

use this line in your view

```
<form action='role/reg' method='post'>
```

and then use the parameter in your reg method.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this by doing a work around to the way of Rails.

```
def index
   if params[:commit] == "REGISTER"
       #some codes...
   elsif params[:commit] == "EDIT/DELETE"
       #some codes...
   end
end
```

That's it. Thanks to @ghayes, I managed to think of a work around.